# How to properly build a design system using material ui

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, es6-modules, parcel

in our company we are trying to build our design system as a package, in order to install it in several of our projects. Building the package works fine, but once we install it and import something from it, we get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../design-system/dist/main.js 5:0-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/Tab' in '/Users/***/***/minimal-example/frontends/design-system/dist'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@mui/material/Tab' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

I have managed to create a quite small project to reproduce the problem, you can find it here: https://github.com/antoniogamizbadger/minimal-example

To reproduce the problem, you just need to clone it and follow these steps:

From `design-system` directory:

```bash
npm ci
npm run build
```

From `package` directory:

```bash
npm ci
npm start
```

We have tried several things but now we are clueless why this is happening. The error message suggests some of the root problems. Nonetheless, we have tried to fix it/research the error without finding any solution.

Any idea what configuration should we change to make this really easy use case work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `design-system` package declares that it is an ESM module via `"type": "module"` in the `package.json`.

Tooling has got a fair amount stricter in recent years in forcing spec-compliance. In your case, it's Webpack being strict about it. But you should be compliant on shared libs anyway. More modern bundlers like [Vite](https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-extensions) try to cover this up a bit but in general, the situation right now as we transition into ESM is a bit of a mess with different tools doing different things.

When you import like this:

```
import TabMaterial  from '@mui/material/Tab'
```

It is a import of a singular file and not a module, so within ESM's spec that would have to be:

```
import TabMaterial  from '@mui/material/Tab.js'
```

Generally, though you shouldn't do this anyway. The internal file structure of Mui is private and liable to change. Just use:

```
import { Tab as TabMaterial } from '@mui/material'
```

You [don't need to worry](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#when-and-how-to-use-tree-shaking) about the effects this has on bundle size.