# Material styles cannot be loaded properly when building design system package

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, es6-modules, rollupjs

In our company, we are trying to build our design system as a package, in order to install it in several of our projects. Building the package works fine, but once we install it and import the theme from it, we get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/design-system/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/styles' in '/Users/***/***/minimal-example/frontends/drupe-mo/node_modules/design-system/dist/esm'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@mui/material/styles' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

I have managed to create a quite small project to reproduce the problem, you can find it here: https://github.com/antoniogamizbadger/minimal-example

To reproduce the problem, you just need to clone it and follow these steps:

From `design-system` directory:

```bash
npm ci
npm run build
```

From `package` directory:

```bash
npm ci
# this is to avoid a symlink being created
rm -rf node_modules/design-system &&  npm install --install-links ../design-system
```

We have tried several things but now we are clueless why this is happening. The error message suggests some of the root problems. Nonetheless, we have tried to fix it/research the error without finding any solution. I asked a really [similar question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461553/how-to-properly-build-a-design-system-using-material-ui), but using the same answer provided there is not working in this case.

**Side note:** we are using Rollup to build the design-system package and importing components is working fine. We have started getting this problem when we have imported the theme from the built package.

Any idea what configuration should we change to make this work?

##### Update

Changing the import from

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

to:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
```

does not solve the issue.